# How to generate adversarial examples by using random Gaussian noise as input belonging to certain class ( Targeted adversarial learning)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, python, adversarial-example

I have a image dataset with two classes: [0,1] and a trained model able to classify these two classes. Now, I want to generate an adversarial example belonging to a certain class, (say 0) by using Gaussian  random noise as input. Precisely, the trained model should classify these adversarial examples generated using Gaussian random noise as class 0. For this, I  have also assumed that I have the information about the gradient of the model under attack. So how do I go about it?

I've done the following so far, which I think is not giving me correct result because the value of loss doesn't change at all during the training process of generating adversarial examples. Can somebody please look into my code and tell me what is that I am doing wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Input, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

classes = [0, 1]

# laod data and labels
data = np.load(r'data.npy')
labels = np.load(r'labels.npy')

# creating one hot encoded labels
labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels, 2)

# split the data and its labels for training and testing purpose
Xtrain, Xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.3, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
print(Xtrain.shape)  

# Normalize: 0,255 -> 0,1
Xtrain, Xtest = Xtrain / 255.0, Xtest / 255.0


# 2) Setup the model
# model...
inputs = Input(shape=(Xtrain.shape[1], Xtrain.shape[2]))
net = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(2, 2),activation='relu')(inputs)
net = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(2, 2),activation='relu')(net)
net = Flatten()(net)
net = Dense(32, activation='relu')(net)
outputs = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(net)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='Image Classifier')
print(model.summary())

# # loss and optimizer
 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

# # training
 batch_size = 64
epochs = 10

model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, batch_size=batch_size , epochs=epochs , verbose=0, validation_data=(Xtest, ytest))

print("Base accuracy on original images:", model.evaluate(x=Xtest, y=ytest, verbose=0))


def clip_eps(tensor):
    # clip the values of the tensor to a given range and return it
    return tf.clip_by_value(tensor, clip_value_min=0,
                            clip_value_max=1)


# Function to generate adversarial examples
def generate_adversaries(noise):
    label = 0

    # iterate over number of steps
    for step in range(0, 200):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # explicitly indicate that our noise should be tacked for
            # gradient updates
            tape.watch(noise)
            # use our model to make predictions on the input noise and
            # then compute the loss
            prediction = model(noise, training=False)
            loss = tf.keras.losses.MSE(label, prediction)

            # check to see if we are logging the loss value, and if
            # so, display it to our terminal
            if step % 20 == 0:
                print("step: {}, loss: {}...".format(step,
                                                     loss.numpy()))

    # calculate the gradients of loss with respect to the noise
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, noise)

    # update the weights and update the value of noise
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([gradients], [noise]))
    noise.assign_add(clip_eps(noise))
    noise = clip_eps(noise)

    return noise


optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)


# Generate and visualize 1 adversarial images
#noise = tf.Variable(np.random.rand(1, 28, 28), trainable=True)
noise = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.rand(1, 28, 28), dtype=tf.float32)
adversary = generate_adversaries(noise)
plt.imshow((adversary * 255).astype(np.uint8))
plt.title(f' Adversary Prediction: {classes[model.predict(adversary).argmax()]}', fontsize=8)
plt.grid('off')
plt.show()
```